# HL7 2.7.1 XML schemas missing <escape> element definition

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, hl7, hl7-v2

We are attempting to exchange HL7 2.7.1 messages using the [XML Encoding Syntax, Release 2](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=275) specification. Some of those messages contain escape sequences in the OBX-5 field. However the [HL7 Version 2.7.1 Messaging Schemas](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=321) don't define the <escape> element anywhere. And the "OBX.5.CONTENT" type isn't defined as mixed. This is causing schema validation to fail on our message XML documents.

Is this a defect in the schema? It doesn't appear to match the written specification. Do we need to customize the schema to make it work or has anyone found another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a defect in the schema. You'll have to customize it to make it work